# c++ : what is the meaning of &&

Tags: c++, c++11, effective-c++

I am new to c++ and I am reading Effective Modern c++ and I don't understand this part

*It’s especially important to remember this when dealing with a parameter of rvalue reference type, because the parameter itself is an lvalue:*

```
Widget(Widget&& rhs);    // rhs is an lvalue, though it has  

…                        // an rvalue reference type
```

Comment: @Barmar I don't think this is a valid duplicate - It does not explain why `rhs` is an lvalue inside `Widget(Widget&&rhs)`. The title of this question does not match its content thought...

Comment: From the end of the first answer: **Named rvalue references are lvalues.**